# Programmatically created trigger is only for current file, despite giving key of other file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to programmatically create a trigger for a Google Spreadsheet when a form is submitted with code from another Spreadsheet, but it won't work. Here is my code:

```
function createOnFormSubmitTrigger()
{
  //Id of "Spreadsheet 1"
  var ssId = "18bq-67nP4y7F9Hp4jzpbKPCyAsR6hglgcfmxCi_zj14";

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("formInput").forSpreadsheet(ssId).onFormSubmit().create();
}
```

If I put that method into "Spreadsheet 1" and run it, it works fine and creates the script in Spreadsheet 1 as intended. However, if I put that method into say "Spreadsheet 2" and run it, it creates the trigger in Spreadsheet 2 instead of Spreadsheet 1, which is not as intended. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for formInput for the original script and the dummy script I made for testing:

Original:

```
function formInput()
{
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var inSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses");

  var data = inSheet.getSheetValues(2,2,1,7);

  var minutes = data[0][0];
  var seconds = data[0][1];
  var numMissed = data[0][2];
  var sgIncorrect = data[0][3];
  var sfMissed = data[0][4];
  var year = data[0][5];
  var testLevel = data[0][6];
  var date = new Date();

  var outSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName(testLevel);

  var testLevelExists = (outSheet != null);

  if(testLevelExists)
  {
    outSheet.insertRowBefore(2);
    outSheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(date.getMonth()+1+ "/" + date.getDate());
    outSheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(year);
    var secStr = ("0" + seconds);
    outSheet.getRange(2,3).setValue(minutes + ":" + secStr.substring(secStr.length-2));
    outSheet.getRange(2,4).setValue(numMissed);
    outSheet.getRange(2,5).setValue(sgIncorrect);
    outSheet.getRange(2,6).setValue(sfMissed);
    outSheet.getRange(2,7).setValue(350-7*(sgIncorrect+numMissed)-2*(sfMissed));
    shiftBox(outSheet);
    setFormulas(outSheet);
    updateAverageTime(outSheet);
    inSheet.deleteRow(2);
    copyToMaster(spreadSheet,outSheet);
  }
}
```

Dummy:

```
function formInput()
{
  var hi = "hello";
}
```

Comment: It's possible you do not have permissions to do what you wish. Are you in a GSuite domain, are these for the same account, etc etc etc.

Comment: @tehhowch I do not know what you mean by GSuite domain, so I am probably not in one. The files are both in sub-folders of a folder that was shared with me, so I'll try it with two files in only my drive and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: so you mean `ssID` value is the `id` of your first spreadsheet is that right?

Comment: Correct @JSmith

Comment: @tehhowch I just tried it and created a new folder in my drive with two spreadsheets named Spreadsheet 1 and Spreadsheet 2, and pasted the code from my other project into these new spreadsheets and it still did not work.

Comment: can you share the `formInput`code. Maybe your using the `getActiveSpreadsheet`function in it

Comment: @JSmith Sure, I'll add the code for both tests in the main post.

Comment: do you have the same linked form to both spreadsheets?

Comment: @JSmith no, the form is only linked to spreadsheet 1.

Comment: @LoganDavenport  I'll wait for the edit

Comment: Consider that creating a form submit trigger probably requires the target spreadsheet to be a form response destination.

Comment: @JSmith I did use the getActiveSpreadsheet in the original formInput, but that shouldn't affect the trigger being created, should it? The same problem was also occuring on the dummy which had no methods being called.

Comment: @tehhowch The target spreadsheet is a form response destination, but I also tried creating an onEdit trigger instead of an onFormSubmit trigger and it still didn't work.

Comment: when you go in both trigger menu of google IDE do you they have both a trigger or do sheet1 have 2 triggers?

Comment: @JSmith if I run the code in Spreadsheet1 it creates the trigger in Spreadsheet 1 but not Spreadsheet 2, but if I run the exact same code in Spreadsheet 2 instead of Spreadsheet 1, it creates the trigger in Spreadsheet 2 and not in Spreadsheet 1.

Comment: Would it help you guys if I gave you a drive link to the dummy folder I'm working with?

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fv72_6YSOuywxTKJvHyJSQHkGicZIlfG

Comment: @JSmith Shared it

Comment: @I'-'I JSmith helped me figure it out. I misunderstood what the trigger creation did. As I now understand it displays the trigger on Spreadsheet 2, but the trigger activates on Spreadsheet 1 using methods from Spreadsheet 2. I'm going to post a response once I fully figure it out from my original example.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to thank @JSmith for all his help first of all. I seemed to have misunderstood the creation of new triggers using the ScriptApp API. When the script is created, it links the trigger to actions performed on the target sheet, but the code must be in the original sheet which created the trigger. The trigger is also only displayed on the sheet which created the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

As seen together,

try all your functions from google's `IDE` once.

Also it seems a trigger created from a certain spreadsheet is viewable from the trigger menu of the original spreadsheet script even if this trigger is linked to another spreadsheet.